# Why do we need multiple keyed by operators in flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

KeyedProcessFunction requires the previous operator to be a keyedBy operator

When I try to process a keyed stream using two KeyedProcessFunctions, why does the second function require me to apply the keyedBy operation again. Shouldn't the stream already be partitioned by keys?

```
var stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer[Event]("flinkkafka", EventSerializer, properties))


var processed_stream_1 = stream
                         .keyBy("keyfield") 
                         .process(new KeyedProcess1())

var processed_stream_2 = processed_stream_1
                         .process(new KeyedProcess2()) //this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2):

With some Flink operations, such as windows and process functions, there is a sort of disconnect between the input and output records, and Flink isn't able to guarantee that the records being emitted still follow the original key partitioning. If you are confident that it's safe to do so, you can use [reinterpretAsKeyedStream](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/experimental.html#reinterpreting-a-pre-partitioned-data-stream-as-keyed-stream) instead of a second keyBy in order avoid an unnecessary network shuffle.